# Calcular valor antes de almacenarlo en la BD Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy usando PostgreSQL y tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
create_table :items do |t|
  t.integer :ventClient
  t.integer :item1
  t.integer :item2
  t.integer :item3
  t.integer :item4

  t.timestamps
end
```

el atributo ventClient es igual a la suma del item1, item2, item3 y item4, quiero que al momento de crear un nuevo item, se almacene el valor de ventClient en función de los valores que ingrese el usuario en item1, item2, item3 y item4.

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un `callback` como `before_save` o `before_validation` (puedes ver la lista completa [aquí](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)) en tu modelo:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_ventClient

  # ...

  private

  def set_ventClient
    self[:ventClient] = item1 + item2 + item3 + item4
  end
end
```